# Zoom in & Out Tool in C#

Tags: c#, button, zooming

I want to be able to have two buttons that allow me to zoom in & out on a picturebox image but currently have no code for this. Please Help Me,

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=196&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these:

[PictureBox Zoom](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/PictureBoxZoom.aspx)
[A scrollable, zoomable, and scalable picture box](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/ScalablePictureBox.aspx)

The second one worked great for a project of mine.  Codeproject has a few more examples.